# Android: Can a memory leak happen on the same thread?

Tags: java, android

I am new to handling the memory leak situations, but one thing that I have noticed is that all the examples showing memory leaks have the activity contexts on a different thread. 
So I need to know if a memory leak can happen if there is an object reference on the same thread as well, because the activity reference is stored somewhere in other classes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: may I ask why this question is downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the reason may be you didn't provide any codes or any errors. So people may think you haven't try anything and just asking suggestion. There is no wonder, if this question is closed. Show your codes and errors or post existing questions in StackOverflow and mention that was not enough. Community expects you have done some research or you are actually in trouble

Answer (score 1):

A Memory Leak is a situation when there are objects present in the heap that are no longer used, but the garbage collector is unable to remove them from memory and, thus they are unnecessarily maintained.
Memory leaks can happend in the same thread as well. For example if a method stored data in a static variable which it does need to refer in the subsequent call.
E.g: In the code below we are storing numbers generates in a static list even though we do not require those generated numbers in subsequent calls.

```
public class MemoryLeak{
    public static List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void doSomething() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            list.add(Math.random());
        }
        Log.info("Debug Point 2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Log.info("Debug Point 1");
        new MemoryLeak().doSomething();
        Log.info("Debug Point 3");
    }
}
```